# How to graphically add a sine and cosine?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

How do I graphically prove that

$$
A\sin{x} + B\cos{x} = \sqrt{A^2 + B^2} \sin{(x + \phi)}
$$

Where $\phi = \arctan{\frac{B}{A}}$

Comment: I don't think you can. There's no way to graphically prove that the resulting picture is a sine wave (I think). If you take for granted that it's a sine wave, then there is a way to deduce the modulus and argument shift, though.

Comment: I remember using a unit circle in a cartesian plane to derive sin(x+y), that's what I meant by "graphically", is there such a method to describe six + cosx?

Comment: Sure. Work through the unit circle derivation of $\sin(x+y)$ step-by-step, applying it to $\sin(x+\phi)$. You'll get expressions like $\sin(\phi)=\sin(\arctan(A/B))$ and $\cos(\phi)=\cos(\arctan(A/B))$. Now work through the graphical derivations line-by-line of identities for $\sin(\arctan(x))$ and $\cos(\arctan(x))$.

Comment: It is possible. Hints: the left hand side is the scalar product $<P,Q>$, where $P=(\cos(x),\sin(x))$ is a point on the unit circle and $Q=(B,A)$ is an arbitrary vector on the plane; the right hand side is $||Q|| \cos(\theta)$, where $\theta$ is the angle $\theta:=x+\phi-\pi/2$. Then you have to show that $\theta$ is the angle between $P$ and $Q$ and use the geometric definition of the scalar product on the plane (note that $||P||=1$).

Comment: See here the geometric definition of the dot product: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product

Comment: However, I think there is a typo. You have to define $\phi=\arctan \frac{B}{A}$

Comment: Yes, it was a typo, my mistake.

Comment: When A and B are both negative, the statement might not be true.

Comment: Mmmh, you are right. I think we have to multiply one of the two sides by sgn$(B)$ or define $\phi$ a bit better.

Comment: For nonpositive $A,$ the given formula is not an identity.